# using gsub extract middle name from name column

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to extract middle name from a column that contains both middle and first names. Essentially I want everything after the first space ex. 'Doe K' from row 2 but no entries if person only has first name (exclude rows 4-6).

**Data below**:

```
nm <- read.table(text = "
             names
             1 'Jack Daniels'
             2 'John Doe K'
             3 'Kelly Susan H'
             4 'Kevin'
             5 'John'
             6 'William'")
```

**Code:**

```
for (i in 1:nrow(nm))
  nm[i,'middle_name'] <- gsub(".*? (.+)","\\1",nm[i, 'names'])
```

**Expected Result:**

```
   names         middle_name
1: Jack Daniels  Daniels
2: John Doe K    Doe K
3: Kelly Susan H Susan H
4: Kevin         NA
5: John          NA
6: William       NA
```

Comment: Try `nm$middle_name = sub("^\\S+\\s+(\\S.*)|.*", "\\1", nm$names)`, although you will need to replace empty values with `NA` (`nm$middle_name[nm$middle_name==""] <- "NA"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> sub("\\w+\\b *", "", nm$names)
[1] "Daniels" "Doe K"   "Susan H" ""        ""        ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(nm$names, "(?<=\\s).*?$")
[1] "Daniels" "Doe K"   "Susan H" NA        NA        NA
```